# TypeORM Cli: migrationsDir seems to be ignored by scripts

Tags: database-migration, typeorm

I am trying to accomplish a simple migration - renaming a column in the users table.
I cannot get the cli to use the migrationsDir to create OR run migrations from.

**MIGRATION CREATION**

When I run 
`npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:create -n UserFullName -d 'server/migration`, there is no problem creating the file in the migrations folder.

Creating migrations without the -d argument just creates the files in the folder root, it ignores the migrationsDir in the Connection Options (see ormconfig.ts down below).

**RUNNING MIGRATIONS**

Running `npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:run` yields exit status 1, My guess is that it can't find the migrations, but I really don't know.

```
Error during migration run:
Error: No connection options were found in any of configurations file.
    at ConnectionOptionsReader.<anonymous> (/Users/matthewshields/Documents/Code/Projects/Sumo/dohyo-dreams/src/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.ts:41:19)
    at step (/Users/matthewshields/Documents/Code/Projects/Sumo/dohyo-dreams/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:133:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/matthewshields/Documents/Code/Projects/Sumo/dohyo-dreams/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:57)
    at fulfilled (/Users/matthewshields/Documents/Code/Projects/Sumo/dohyo-dreams/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/matthewshields/Documents/Code/Projects/Sumo/dohyo-dreams/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:157:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./server/server.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "breakpoint-sass": "^2.7.1",
    "chroma-js": "^2.0.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.9.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "envalid": "^4.1.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.16.1",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "massive": "^5.7.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "pg": "^7.11.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sumo-rank": "^1.0.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.11",
    "husky": "^1.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.1",
    "typescript": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node ./server/server.ts",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start-sw": "express ./build",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "typeorm:cli": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

server.ts

```
require('dotenv').config();
import { } from 'reflect-metadata';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import App from './app';
import * as config from './ormconfig';

import RankingsController from './rankings/rankings.controller';
import RankChartsController from './rankCharts/rankCharts.controller';
import TournamentsController from './tournaments/tournaments.controller';
import UsersController from './users/users.controller';
import validateEnv from './utils/validateEnv';
import WrestlersController from './wrestlers/wrestlers.controller';

validateEnv();

(async () => {
  try {
    await createConnection(config);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error while connecting to the database', error);
    return error;
  }
  const app = new App(
    [
      new TournamentsController(),
      new WrestlersController(),
      new RankingsController(),
      new RankChartsController(),
      new UsersController(),
    ],
  );
  app.listen();
})();
```

apps.ts

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as express from 'express';
import Controller from './interfaces/interface.controller';
import errorMiddleware from './middleware/error.middleware';

class App {
  public app: express.Application;

  constructor(controllers: Controller[]) {
    this.app = express();

    this.initializeMiddlewares();
    this.initializeErrorHandling();
    this.initializeControllers(controllers);
  }

  public listen() {
    this.app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log(`App listening on the port ${process.env.PORT}`);
    });
  }

  private initializeMiddlewares() {
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
  }

  private initializeErrorHandling() {
    this.app.use(errorMiddleware);
  }

  private initializeControllers(controllers: Controller[]) {
    controllers.forEach((controller) => {
      this.app.use('/', controller.router);
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

ormconfig.ts

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

const config: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  entities: [
    __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
  ],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'server',
  }
}
export = config;
```

(timestamp)-UserFullName.ts

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

export class UserFullName1574403715918 implements MigrationInterface {

  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" RENAME "fullName" to "name"`);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" RENAME "name" to "fullName"`);
  }
}
```

I suspect my file structure may be related to the issue, so I have listed it briefly. I just listed some the basics, there are more controllers and entities for Tournaments, Wrestlers, Rankings, Rankcharts.

```
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── package.json
├── src
├── server
│   ├── ormconfig.ts
│   ├── server.ts
│   ├── app.ts
│   ├── users
│   │   ├── users.controller.ts
│   │   ├── users.dto.ts
│   │   ├── users.entity.ts
│   ├── migration
```

First time poster, any constructive criticism on my format or explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming across similar issues, these were good nuggets I valued:

1. The typeorm CLI reads the `cli.migrationsDir` (from ormconfig.ts) **only when creating migrations (not reading).** You can see that subtle distinction [here in the docs](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations) - it reads:

   > "*...`"cli": { "migrationsDir": "migration" }` - indicates that the
   > CLI must create new migrations in the "migration" directory.*"
2. This was confusing - why would it need a separate config just for writing? Wouldn't reading/writing migrations be the same config? I don't know, still don't know - but I confirmed this by reading the source as well (unless I whiffed something).
3. Final conclusion: It's likely those configs (`migrations: [...]` & `cli.migrationsDir`) should point to the same location on the filesystem unless you have a good reason not to.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much, the documentation is not clear about these informations have to be in the ormconfig.json file !

Comment: Very helpful answer, but it would be even better to include links to the parts of the source code that confirmed this

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here's because you use async connection. I had the same issue and managed to solve it after I've added the `ormconfig.ts` (should work with `.js` also) file with the synchronous connection.

In the config file you should add the cli property`cli: {migrationsDir: "server/migration"}`

To be able to run migrations using cli another property is needed: `migrations: [join(__dirname, 'server/migration/*{.ts,.js}')],`

Also when running cli you should indicate where this config file is located `--config path/to/ormconfig.ts` flag.

The full command example with ts: `ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate --config server/ormconfig.ts`

For more info you can check this example https://github.com/ambroiseRabier/typeorm-nestjs-migration-example I found it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems by your file structure the config should look like that:

ormconfig.ts

```
export const config: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    ...
    migrations: ['server/migration/*.js', 'server/migration/*.ts'],
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: 'server/migration',
    },
};
```

You might need get the `ormconfig.ts` file out of the `server` folder to sit on the same level as `package.json`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you reach the correct migration file path?

```
{
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: "src/migration"
    }
}
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-cli.md

Comment: if this is an answer then please add extra details and explanation. And if this was intended as new question then use proper button to create new question without high-jacking old question.